# jQuery - ajax call and animation

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am trying to bring in some effects on a div after an ajax call. This is my jQuery for ajax, ajax works very well but none of effects I try to bring in here from script. 
How do I make it possible? I want the new data to be shown in a div with a slideDown effect.

```
function item_submit(){
    $('#item_item_button').click(function() {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: "/item/create",
            data: $('#create_item').serialize(),
            error: function(){  },
            success: function(data) {
                $("#item_form").hide();
                $('#view_item').html(data);
            },
            complete: function() {
                $('#view_item').slideDown();
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
}
```

Comment: do you have any errors in firebug?

Comment: What is your HTML structure? Is `#view_item` within `#item_form`?

Comment: @p0rter, I haven't tried firebug. Lemme try it real quick.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan - No those are no within each other. Both are under a div 'center'. 
`<div id="center"> <div id="view_item"> .... </div> 
<div id="item_form"> .... </div>  </div>`

Comment: @p0rter - Tried firebug, I don't see errors. Basically after ajax call I want the form div 'item_form' to hide and display div 'view_item' with a sliding down effect, this div is partial rendered and the item data returned from the ajax call. Both div are under div 'center'.

Answer (score 0):

Try with below code:

```
function item_submit(){
    $('#item_item_button').click(function() {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: "/item/create",
            data: $('#create_item').serialize(),
            error: function(){  },
            success: function(data) {
               $('#item_form').before(data);
               $('#view_item').hide().slideDown('slow');

            }

    });
    return false;
});
```

}

Comment: Chandresh, I tried this but didn't bring the sliding effect. Basically  after ajax call I want the form div 'item_form' to hide and display div 'view_item' with a sliding down effect, this div is partial rendered and the item data returned from the ajax call. Both div are under div 'center'.